# Normal approximation of binomial distribution with finite n corrections

Tags: probability, analysis, statistics

I know I can approximate binomial distribution $B(n,p)$ with normal distribution
$N(np,np(1-p))$.

For finite $n$, I assume there are correction terms for mean and variance of the normal distribution, i.e. when $n$ is finite, a more accurate normal 
approximation to $B(n,p)$ should be $N(np+A, np(1-p)+B)$, where $A$ and $B$ depend on $n$ and go to $0$ when $n\to \infty$.

Is there known formulas for $A$ and $B$?

Comment: You might be interested in http://www.unomaha.edu/wwwmath/OurArchive/KerriganMinigrants/2009_2010/2009_2010/BeichenWang_KRMP10.pdf

Answer (score 1):

No, that isn't the way you correct for small sample normal approximation of the binomial.  The correction is applied with respect to the fact that  a sum of discrete probability masses doesn't behave the same as an integral of a continuous probability density.

For a simple example, suppose $X$ is discrete and $Y$ is a continuous approximation of $X$.  The statement $\Pr[X = 2]$, assuming that $X$ can actually take on the value $2$ with some nonzero probability, is meaningful, but $\Pr[Y = 2] = 0$ because $Y$ is continuous.  So, a naive approximation would be to say something like $$\Pr[X = 2] \approx \Pr[1.5 < Y \le 2.5].$$  We don't *have* to use $\pm 0.5$, of course, but it is one way to do such a continuity correction.  It is worthwhile to note that such correction is completely independent of any parameters of the distributions themselves.

So, for the normal approximation to the binomial, let's try an example.  Suppose $X \sim \operatorname{Binomial}(n = 53, p = 0.61)$.  We wish to approximate this using a suitable normal distribution so that we may calculate $$\Pr[11 \le X < 35].$$  To this end, let $$Y \sim \operatorname{Normal}(\mu = np = 32.33, \sigma^2 = np(1-p) = 12.6087).$$  Then we have $$\begin{align*} \Pr[11 \le X < 35] &\approx \Pr[10.5 \le Y \le 34.5] \\ &= \Pr\left[\frac{10.5-32.33}{\sqrt{12.6087}} \le \frac{Y - \mu}{\sigma} \le \frac{34.5-32.33}{\sqrt{12.6087}} \right] \\ &= [-6.14778 \le Z \le 0.611117] \\ &= 0.729439 - 3.92865 \times 10^{-10} = 0.729439. \end{align*}$$  Take note of the *direction* of the correction:  if $X$ includes the probability mass at one endpoint (here, $X = 11$ is included), the correction is adjusted to include the half-integer interval beyond it; if $X$ does *not* include the endpoint ($X = 35$ is *not* included), then the correction is adjusted to *exclude* the half-integer interval up to that value.

Without correction, the probability we would have obtained is $0.773953$.  The *exact* probability, computed by summing $$\Pr[11 \le X < 35] = \sum_{x=11}^{34} \binom{53}{x} (0.61)^x (0.39)^{53-x} = 0.727048.$$  So as you can see, the continuity correction that was applied gives a far superior result.

Could you conceivably derive an adjustment to the normal mean and variance that performs as well as this method of correction?  I strongly doubt it, for it would need to take into account whether you mean $$\Pr[\ell < X < u], \quad \Pr[\ell \le X < u], \quad \Pr[\ell < X \le u], \quad \Pr[\ell \le X \le u],$$ not to mention the values of $\ell$ and $u$ themselves in relation to the parameters $n$ and $p$.  And even if it could be done, it is likely to be a more complicated algorithm to apply than what we have shown here.

Comment: If this is closer to what you're looking for, then Jim Pitman's probability book (Springer) has a method of improving the normal fit to the binomial by taking binomial skewness into account. Can't find my copy right now, but if you want to pursue it, I think it's somewhere around p100 in his book. (You may be able to preview some pages online.)

Answer (score 1):

I believe you may have used $n$ in two different ways in your question.
And maybe you are asking for a comparison of the binomial and the hypergeometric probability distributions.

**Binomial.** If we are sampling from an (essentially) infinite population, or from
a finite population without replacement, then the binomial distribution
applies. The number of observations is denoted $n$ and the probability
of a certain occurrence, often generically called as Success is $p$.

*Examples:* (1) Many public opinion polls sample $n$ people from the
population of a state, where $n$ is several hundred or maybe as large
as a couple of thousand, and the number of people in the state is
several million. An answer in favor of a particular candidate might be
called a Success. (2) We roll a fair die $n$ times and the probability
of getting a 6 (a Success) on each roll is $p = 1/6$. Conceivably, the
die can be rolled infinitely many times.

In both of these examples,
questions about the number $X$ of Successes we may see out of $n$ can be answered
using the binomial distribution. The mean number of successes is $\mu = np$ and the variance of the number of successes is $\sigma^2 = np(1-p).$ Furthermore, as you suggest, there
are situations in which it is convenient and reasonably accurate to
approximate binomial probabilities using a normal distribution with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2.$

**Hypergeometric:** If you are sampling $n$ items for a population of finite size $N$, then the situation changes somewhat. The main issue is that the
population may become depleted as the sampling goes forward. Roughly speaking, the effects of this depletion begin to be important when the sample size $n$ gets to be more than about 10% of the population size $N.$

*Example:* You are choosing $n = 20$ computer chips out of a shipment
of $N = 100$ in order to see if they are good (a Success) or bad. Maybe
there are 80 good chips among the 100 so that the proportion of Successes
is $p = 90/100 = 0.9$. With random sampling, this is also the probability
of Success as each chip is chosen for testing. You do not put a chip back
with the untested chips, so when you are getting ready choose the last of the 20 chips, you are sampling from a reduced population of only 81 untested chips. Let $X$ be the number of Successes (good chips) out of $n = 20$. The average number is $\mu = np = 20(90/100) = 20(.9) = 18.$ This formula is essentially the same as the formula for the mean of a binomial distribution. However, the variance of $X$ is 
$$\sigma^2 = np(1-p)\frac{N-n}{N-1} = 20(.9)(.1)(80/99) = 1.4545.$$

This formula for the variance is similar to the formula for the variance of a binomial distribution, but *not* exactly the same. The difference is the last factor. It is easy to see that this factor $(N-n)/(N-1)$ tends to 1 as $N \rightarrow \infty.$

Again here, in appropriate circumstances, it may be useful to approximate
probabilities involving $X$ using a normal distribution with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2.$

So it is correct that in the finite population (hypergeometric) case, that a "correction" needs to be made, and also that the correction becomes negligible for huge $N.$ The differences from your guess in the formula with $A$ and $B$, are twofold: (a) there is no correction in the mean $\mu$ and
(b) the correction to the variance $\sigma^2$ is a multiplicative factor rather than a term that needs to be added on. Sometimes this multiplicative
factor is called the ***finite population correction.***

*References:* If you want formulas for computing probabilities with the binomial or hypergeometric distribution you can find them in any basic probability book and many elementary statistics books. You can also google
'binomial distribution' and 'hypergeometric' distribution for online references. As this is written in late March 2015 the Wikipedia pages seem useful, even though they may have more technical detail than you need.